# Problem to Open a Modal using Jquery (jquery-3.6.1.min.js) with Bootstrap 5.2.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am trying to open a modal from jquery and it´s not working
Was working before I upgrade to Jquery and Bootstrap versions.
Any ideas?

---

- JQUERY CODE -

---

```
$("#exampleModal").modal();
```

---

- JSP CODE -

---

I am using the code from the Bootstrap page :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
let modalId = document.getElementById("exampleModal");

const myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modalId);

myModal.modal("show");
```

in the documentation you provided under "via javascript" it looks like you need to initialize it first with `getOrCreateInstance` or `new bootstrap.Modal()` and then showing it via the instance itself and not using the jquery tag selector.

you can also add options for the modal as a second argument to `getOrCreateInstance` using json